# Running my nestjs app on cloud, runs without error but no response on sending a request

Tags: nestjs, production

I'm trying to run my nest app on cloud but sending a request to it returns nothing

npm run build
npm run start:prod 
works fine with no errors
but when i send a request like through postman it just shows sending 
tried using curl also same does not return anything

same code works fine on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

How is your code determining the port to use? If you've hard-coded a port number, chances are that is not the port your cloud provider is using.

Comment: thanks for the reply beast but i made sure i was listening to all the port available in case my hard coded port is not availabe

Comment: Actually there was something already running on my server i think thats what caused the problem i changed the configuration and now its working fine

Comment: Sweet! I'm glad you figured it out